# Calling a vectorized function in numba

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numba

I'm trying to call a @vectorize function from a @jit function. ¿Could someone explain why is not working?
I post the code and the error:

```
N = 1000
# Ufunc using numba
@vectorize('float64(float64,float64)',nopython = True,target = "parallel")
def function(x,y):
    return x+y

# Jitted function calling the previous function
@jit('float64[:](float64[:],float64[:])',nopython = True)
def test_function(x,y):
    return function(x,y)

x = np.zeros(N)
y = np.ones(N)
vector = test_function(x,y)
```

The error message I get is:
**Untyped global name 'function': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numpy.ufunc'>**

It only happens when you add the flag `target='parallel'`

Comment: Have you imported `add`? Do you mean `np.add`?

Comment: I have changed the names of the functions to avoid confusion with the numpy module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with the current version of Numba, see:
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5720

You can workaround it by using `target="cpu`.

Comment: Thank you very much!